# Why DP solution for "Maximum Points You Can Obtain from Cards" problem is too slow?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given this problem:

> There are several cards arranged in a row, and each card has an
> associated number of points The points are given in the integer array
> cardPoints.
>
> In one step, you can take one card from the beginning or from the end
> of the row. You have to take exactly k cards.
>
> Your score is the sum of the points of the cards you have taken.
>
> Given the integer array cardPoints and the integer k, return the
> maximum score you can obtain.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: cardPoints = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1], k = 3
>
> Output: 12
>
> Explanation: After the first step, your score will always be 1. However,
> choosing
> the rightmost card first will maximize your total score. The optimal
> strategy is to take the three cards on the right, giving a final score
> of 1 + 6 + 5 = 12.
>
> Constraints:
>
> - 1 <= cardPoints.length <= 10^5
> - 1 <= cardPoints[i] <= 10^4
> - 1 <= k <= cardPoints.length

I believe I wrote a top-down dp solution with memoization, but after submitting the code I see a Time Limit Exceeded error. What is wrong with this solution?

```
class Solution {
    
    Map<String, Integer> cache = new HashMap<>();
    
    public int maxScore(int[] cardPoints, int k) {
        return max(0, cardPoints.length - 1, cardPoints, k);
    }
    
    private int max(int start, int end, int[] cardPoints, int k) {
        if (k == 1) return Math.max(cardPoints[start], cardPoints[end]);
        
        String key = "" + start + end;
        Integer value = cache.get(key);
        if (value != null) {
            return value;
        }
        
        value = Math.max(
            cardPoints[start] + max(start + 1, end, cardPoints, k - 1),
            cardPoints[end] + max(start, end - 1, cardPoints, k - 1)            
        );
        
        cache.put(key, value);
        
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: `String key = "" + start + end;` is suspicious (you probably want something like `start + ";" + end`), but the TLE is because you're not using the asymptotically most efficient algorithm.

Comment: DP in this case is prob. not efficient enough, most approach use `prefix sum`.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat what's the difference between `"" + start + end` and `start + ";" + end`?

Comment: @DanielHao there aren't enough cached results? Or the recursion is making it slow?

Comment: @DiegoMarin does cache key `378` correspond to `3, 78` or `37, 8`?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Note that `start` and `end` are indexes, not vaules. As `k <= cardPoints.length`, I don't see how `end` could be less than `start`. Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: `1234` is `1, 234` or `12, 34` then.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat now I see, thank you.

Comment: Problem is [here](https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-points-you-can-obtain-from-cards/) (LeetCode #1423). Recursion can't possibly work because the input size is 10^5, meaning you might need to allocate as many stack frames.

Comment: @ggorlen You're right. Seems that "For a 64 bits Java 8 program with minimal stack usage, the maximum number of nested method calls is about 7000"

Answer (score 1):

Your caching-algorithm stores each and every intermediate step. And there's a lot of these. Take for example the simple case of picking four values, and all possible paths your algorithm takes to pick two on each side:

```
1 2 ... 4 3
1 3 ... 4 2
1 4 ... 3 2
3 4 ... 2 1
...
```

In total there's 6 different paths. And all of them lead to the same result. In total this simple example already generates 9 states in your cache. For the upper bound of 10^5, things look even worse. There's a total of

```
(10^5 + 1) * 10^5 / 2 = 5000050000
```

(yup, that's 5 billion) possible states. And each single one of them will be explored. So without the TLE you'd simply run out of memory.

Instead you could use the following considerations to build a more efficient algorithm:

- the order in which values are picked from either side doesn't matter for the final result
- any value that is not taken from the left side must be taken from the right side and vice versa. So if `k` values must be picked in total and `l` are taken from the left side of the array, then `k - l` values must be taken from the right side.

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning complexity O(k) solution